# Mandarin equivalent of 轉行 (zyun3 hong4), which means to switch industries?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

In Cantonese, you often say 轉行 (zyun3 hong4) to say "switch industries". What's the Mandarin equivalent?

Comment: bkrs：zhuǎnháng 转行 ① 从一个行业转到另一个行业；改行。
② 写字、打字或排版等，从一行转到下一行：抄稿时，标点符号尽量不要转行。[change one's profession] 改行

Comment: This term is used in both Cantonese and Mandarin

Comment: 行 is pronounced /hong/ not /haang/ in Cantonese.

Comment: 换行 is similar to 转行, both means **to change profession** and **to start a newline**. In almost all cases, we use 转行 for **changing profession**, equals to 改行 in this case, and 换行 for **starting a new line**.

Comment: It's zyun3 h**o**ng4. 行 ha[a]ng4 vs hong4 vs hang6...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: **《广州话-普通话》** indicates that 转行 is

> 粤

Cantonese. This has probably changed since it was published but they also give the Mandarin equivalents:

> 改行；转业

**《广州话方言词典》** also gives the same two Mandarin equivalent words, in opposite order:

> 转业；改行

**改行** is probably the most colloquial option.

Comment: thanks so much! do you mind sharing this cantoese-to-mandarin dictionary you used?

Comment: @Crashalot They're both Pleco add-on's. You can find their descriptions here: https://store.pleco.com/products.php?ios=1 `Guangzhouhua Fangyan Cidian - $9.99 (version 3 only)
Chinese-Chinese dictionary of Cantonese-specific vocabulary with approximately 8000 entries, from Commercial Press.` && `Guangzhouhua-Putonghua Cidian - $9.99 (version 3 only)
Cantonese-to-Mandarin (focused on diffs between them), 10k entries`. It's probably better to purchase in app though.

Answer (score 0):

转行 is also acceptable in Mandarin. Here's a dictionary entry indicating that it's an alternative to 改行:

> ◎ 转行 zhuǎnháng
>
> [change one’s profession] 改行
>
> http://www.zdic.net/c/c/18/38682.htm

If you search for 转行 you will also find many non-Cantonese-specific results, like this: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%BD%AC%E8%A1%8C